# How to verify a method is called N times exactly in specs2?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, specs2

In specs2, I can verify the invocation times of a method by:

```
there was one(user).getName
there were two(user).getName
there were three(user).getName
```

But how to check N times? Something I'm looking for is like:

```
there were times(n, user).getName
```

Unlucky there is no such API

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation of the specs2 bindings for mockito, you'll find something like

```
def one[T <: AnyRef](mock: T)(implicit anOrder: Option[InOrder] = inOrder()): T =
  verify(mock, org.mockito.Mockito.times(1))(anOrder)
```

So I guess you can just define your own `times` method, by mimicking that one:

```
def times[T <: AnyRef](n: Int, mock: T)(implicit anOrder: Option[InOrder] = inOrder()): T =
  verify(mock, org.mockito.Mockito.times(n))(anOrder)
```

or simply use mockito explicitly:

```
val mocker = new MockitoMocker {}
verify(user, org.mockito.Mockito.times(42)).getName
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an omission. I have just added `exactly` to the API and published it as [specs2-mock-2.4.7-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/specs2/specs2-mock_2.11/2.4.7-SNAPSHOT/) for now (an official release should follow soon):

```
val list2 = mock[java.util.List[String]]
1 to 2 foreach { i => list.add("one") }

there was exactly(2)(list).add("one")
```